# Telerik report grouping not showing all data

Tags: asp.net, telerik, report, objectdatasource, telerik-reporting

I am creating a telerik report, in which i applied grouping based on a grouping parameter.
(SectionID) thats is bound to a data base table through ObjectDataSource.
when i render my report it always shows all records based on First sectionID and not showing all other sectionID(2,3..so on) records.. Below is the example of my output and required output. Please give me your suggestion about how to do it? thanks.

**Required Output:**

```
SectionID        ProductName           Code
```

---

```
1                  Retail1                 123              
                   Retail2                 456

2                Catering1                 450
                 Catering2                 550
```

**My Output:**

```
SectionID        ProductName           Code
```

---

```
1                  Retail1                 123              
                   Retail2                 456
```

Comment: any person use telerik report grouping n subgrouping.. please help?

Comment: Are you selecting all groups in your grouping parameters? Have a look here http://tv.telerik.com/watch/reporting/video/telerik-trainer-reporting-grouping

Comment: Yes i used grouping parameters and the same method as described in this link. My report grouping is working fine now :)  .. telerik grouping renders all data as described in above link. Due to large amount of data i couldnot differenciate it well earlier. thanks for the help. :)